# React, pass prop as function argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
<div id="board" onClick={(event) => 
                         this.props.boardClicked(event)}>
```

I would like to pass a second argument trying something like this, but my syntax is off I think:

```
<div id="board" 
   onClick={(event, {this.props.activeCharacter}) =>
            this.props.boardClicked(event, {this.props.activeCharacter})}>
```

Comment: you shouldn't need the `{}` for `{this.props.activeCharacter}`. You also shouldn't need any arguments for the first part of the function either. E.g. `(event, {this.props.activeCharacter}) =>` can just be `() =>`

Answer (score 1):

Simple change would be that because you are using an arrow function it is lexically bound automatically to the react compmponent instance, so you can use `this` within function. Simply pass as an extra arg from within the function

```
<div id="board" onClick={(event) => this.props.boardClicked(event, this.props.activeCharacter)}>
```

Using arrow functions in event handlers in react is a bad idea though because it creates an anonymous function, that will cause this component to unnecessarily always re-render which can hurt performance if component is used a lot

You can overcome that by defining a handler on your class

```
onBoardClick = (event) => this.props.boardClicked(event, this.props.activeCharacter)

render = () => <div id="board" onClick={this.onBoardClick} />
```

Now you are passing the same function reference each time so no unnecessary re-renders but same click handler functionality

Comment: By the way I don't know your situation, but it is rare to pass the event down to handlers passed in as props - it is normally just used locally to stop event propagation or derive some value from it, which is then passed to your handler. 

You could probably suffice without the `event` arg in `this.props.boardClicked` and just pass the character `onBoardClick = (event) => this.props.boardClicked(this.props.activeCharacter)` changing the `boardClicked` signature elsewhere to suit of course